# Java, Apache POI, cell value won't change when seen from MS Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to modify an existing Excel file (something.xls).
After I set a cell value using:

```
sheet.getRow(3).getCell(30).setCellValue(222);
```

I can see the changes reading the value from the same cell with:

```
 sheet.getRow(3).getCell(30).toString();
```

BUT when I'm opening the something.xls file with MS Excel the change is gone.

Now the funny part:

- -If I'm rerunning the code without the line where I set the cell value, I can still see 222, so the change is there, only I see the
  old value from MS Excel for some reason.
- -I triple checked to make sure I'm not editing a different file from code and opening another with Excel.
- -I tried changing some other random cells in a similar way and some work, while others do not. (the cells do not contain formulas and all
  are numeric type)

I would really appreciate if anyone could offer an explanation and solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the cell type before you set the value: `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);`

Comment: Is that cell perhaps a Formula cell?

Comment: I am also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of the existing excel file (manually, without any formatting) to a new one and formatted it again. It is working now. I must have set something wrong the first time, I couldn't figure out what though. Thanks for the replies.